# How to show status of a SP user in the Search results?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, people-search

In sharepoint online I am searchuing users from peaople directory there i want to show status of searched users like online, away, offline, busy, etc.
so which is the best approach to achive this?

My result look alike as below image

[image]

That rectangular left vertical line is supposed to show in various colors as green for available/online..... Etc

Comment: Just want to confirm that if you want to add rectangular left vertical line , or the left vertical line are already exist but didn't show the status of users ?

Comment: already exist but didn't show the status of users

Answer (score 2):

Add following div tag where presence icon need to be displayed:
[image]
then insert the following code near the bottom of your template. This code registers a callback to load the script and display the presence icon for you.

```
AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function(){
EnsureScriptFunc("clienttemplates.js", "RenderUserFieldWorker", function() {
    var getUserPersona = function() {
        var renderCtx = new ContextInfo();
        renderCtx.Templates = {};
        renderCtx.Templates["Fields"] = {};
        var fieldSchemaData = { "DefaultRender":"1", "PictureSize": "None"};
        var listSchema = {"EffectivePresenceEnabled": "1", "PresenceAlt": Srch.Res.item_People_NoPresenceAvailable};
        var userData = {"title": uName, "email": uEmail, "picture": uPicUrl, "sip": uSip};
        var personaControlElement = document.getElementById(userPersonaId);
        if (!Srch.U.n(personaControlElement))
        {
            personaControlElement.innerHTML = RenderUserFieldWorker(renderCtx, fieldSchemaData, userData, listSchema);
        }
        if(typeof(ctx.EnqueueImnRequest) == "undefined") { ctx.EnqueueImnRequest = false; }
        if (ctx.EnqueueImnRequest == false) {
            ctx.ClientControl.add_oneTimeResultRendered(function(){ if (typeof(ProcessImn) != "undefined") { ProcessImn(); } });
            ctx.EnqueueImnRequest = true;
        }
    };
    getUserPersona();
});
});
```

Comment: the same code i have and that is not giving me any status of user.

Comment: Is it displaying offline or no status at all?The Presence only becomes available when you have Lync setup correctly. For Office 365 use the Desktop Setup to accomplish this. https://portal.microsoftonline.com/OLS/mysoftware.aspx?source=ehome

Comment: I havent setuped lync

Answer (score 1):

Are your users using Lync or Skype for Business? This code has two requirements.

1. You are tracking presence with Lync (on-prem) or Skype for Business (Online) and the users are logged in.
2. On the code page itself each Persona container must have a unique ID on the page. In the above code that is the `userPersonaID` value. If you have 5 people on the page there need to be 5 unique ID values.

You can review additional details about the control here: http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2013/06/05/add-presence-to-sharepoint-search-results/